# Passing text from UITextView to string in different ViewController

Tags: objective-c, string, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I need to pass the text of a UITextView in viewController1 to viewController2 and set the text to a string in viewController2. I thought I had the code figured out, but it turns out that nothing is being passed. 
In viewController2.h I added 
    viewController1*v1
and assigned a property to it. 
in the viewController2.m

```
 -(void)method{
  v1=[[viewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1"  bundle:nil];
NSString *text=[[NSString alloc]init];
[v1.tweetText setText:text];
}
```

This is probably the wrong way to go about it, so does anyone have other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the correct way to send data to another vc, but you are not setting the variable `text` to anything. Try setting it to `hello` and see if you get `hello` as the tweetText in the other vc.

Comment: well, I actually use the string text to update twitter, and I did try to set text=@"something" my app tweeted, but I need the text from the textview to get sent to text and thus gets sent to twitter